# API working on browser but not on device with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an app using phonegap. I am using the edmunds API to get pictures of cars. The API works fine on the browser but when I run it on the device it does not show the images. Does anyone know the reason? And is there a way to debug on the device for javascript?

Here is the code:

```
 <script>
    window.sdkAsyncInit = function() {
        // Instantiate the SDK
        var res = new EDMUNDSAPI('xxxx');
        // Optional parameters
        var options = {};
        var style;
        // Callback function to be called when the API response is returned
        function success(res) {

            style = res.styles[0].id;
            console.log(style);

            showimage(style);

        };
        function showimage(style){

            var opt = {
                "styleId": ""+style+"",
                "comparator": "simple"
            };
        console.log(opt);
            res.api('/v1/api/vehiclephoto/service/findphotosbystyleid', opt, success2, fail);

        }
        function success2(res){
            var body = document.getElementById('image');
            body.innerHTML = "<img src='http://media.ed.edmunds-media.com"+ res[0].photoSrcs[0] +"' />";
        }

        function fail(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
        // Fire the API call
        var make = localStorage.getItem('make');
        var model = localStorage.getItem('model');
        var year = localStorage.getItem('year');
        console.log(make+model+year);

        res.api('/api/vehicle/v2/'+make+'/'+model+'/'+year+'/styles', options, success, fail);
        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
        var js, sdkjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "./edmunds.api.sdk.js";
        sdkjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, sdkjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'edmunds-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

http://debug.phonegap.com/ (also known as weinre)

Did you enable the API in the whitelist?

And do you have an adb logcat?

Comment: I enabled the API in the whitelist and weinre is awesome. Thanks! But still the API won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

the API was getting the protocol from the window which was not working for the phone app changed it to https and it worked.